# Coupled DC/DC-modules - correct input filtering

Tags: dc-dc-converter, emi-filtering, dual

According to the support from TracoPower I use two THN-30WI modules (­±15V) in conjunction as shown below (without each C1 and C2) to produce ±30V.
[image]
This works but I get a lot of noise.

The application note explains how to filter *one* module according to EN55022 Class B:
[image]
I would like to apply that filter to my two-module-setup. How do I place capacitors C4 and C5, when **-Vout**, **+Vout** and **COM** are at completely different voltages than in a single-module-setup? Or is that irrelevant and do I still place them across (**-Vout** and **-Vin**) and (**+Vout** and **+Vin**)?

Thank you!

Comment: A lot of noise where?

Comment: I have more trouble on the output side, which has not much to do with the input filter, but this triggered my ambition to filter everything as good as possible. Let's say I want to use Class B filtering, mainly because I want to see, what difference it makes.

Comment: What does the data sheet say that the output noise will be and have you applied the correct load to the device (some devices work poorly on no load current). And finally, why are you using diodes in series with the outputs?

Comment: Minimum load is not required. With a constant load of 1..2kR the noise is much bigger than with no load. Input ripple specification is 30mA(p-p) and output ripple 60mV (p-p). The diodes are recommended by the technical support of TracoPower. It would not be wise for _me_ to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion C4 and C5 might be needed to meet EMC / EMI requirements.

From the emi-considerations document (in one of the ZIP files) I see that C4 and C5 are 2 kV capacitors of 1 nF or 2.2 nF. That are typical values for such EMI capacitors.

These capacitors are there to provide a return path for the high frequency switching signal used inside the DCDC converter. Without them there is no "proper" return path and that can result in the high frequencies being emitted from anything that is connected to the outputs of the DCDC converter.

My advise would be to just follow the advise of the document and place a C4 between -Vin, -Vout and a C5 between +Vin, +Vout. So 2 caps for each DCDC converter. 1 nF or 2.2 nF doesn't really matter.

My guess is that your 12 V input is already mains isolated, in that case the 2 kV rating for the capacitors is also not needed, you could just use standard (50 V) caps.

Comment: Thank you, I will test that. The 12V supply is indeed isolated by an AC/DC-converter (230V / 12V). Is _that_ the reason for the 2kV-specification?

Comment: These TracoPower DCDC converters support up to 1500 V voltage difference between input and output. As these EMI caps are between input and output, they also need to support at least 1500 V **if** you would want to have such a high potential difference. In your case the isolation is in your AC power adapter making the 12 V. So you don't **need** the caps to support a high voltage, there **is** no high voltage in your application. **If** the 12 V was mains connected / live then you would need 2 kV caps for safety reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt matter so much where you place C4 and C5 schematically but it matters where you place it on the board.

These caps return common mode switch currents to input ground. They are not just good for EMI but good practice for a clean power supply.

Assuming you have plenty of ceramice capacitance between +/-30 V and COM, you can place a single cap between COM and GND. Alternatively, you can add 2 more caps from +30 and -30 to GND,  but those arent really necessary if you have low impedance caps from +/-30 to COM.

In the layout, place those caps, so the current can flow from the output to the input through those caps in a path that is very close to the converter, i.e. backside under the converter or topside right beside the converter.